# 'add' button in the knockout template causes an error

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-templating

Trying to include an add button within my knockout template as shown below although I get the following error.  If I move the button outside the template and below the form it works strangely..  Any ideas why this is happening?
Thanks,

**Template**

```
<script type="text/html" id="mytemplate">   

<table data-bind="foreach: Keywords">
<tr>
  <td data-bind="text: $data"></td>
  <td>
      <a href="#" data-bind="click: $root.delete">Delete</a>
  </td>
</tr>
</table>

<input data-bind="value: toAdd" > <button data-bind="click: add">Add</button>   

</script>
```

**Mark up**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm...)      
{
  <div data-bind="template: { name: 'mytemplate', data: mydata}"></div>
}
```

**Error**

```
Error: Error: Unable to parse bindings.
Message: ReferenceError: toAdd is not defined;
Bindings value: value: toAdd
```

**Javascript (onload)**

```
window.Helper = {
    Start: function (tag) {
        var viewModel = viewModel(tag);
        window.helper.ViewModel = viewModel; 
        viewModel.toAdd = ko.observable();
        viewModel.add = function () {  
            ...
        };
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Comment: In your error you have `toAdd`. Where do you have this property in your ViewModel?

Comment: You probably already know this, but that code is going to look for a `toAdd` property on the current binding object (same object that has the `keywords` property).  Can you post more of your view model code?

Comment: i've added where the apply binding is used.

Comment: try `$root.toAdd` and that should work if my assumptions are correct

Comment: Where do you call `ko.applyBindings` is irrelevant in this case... what we need to know how exactly your viewmodel looks like with all the properties what you have in your `mytemplate`. Because you have binding context problems so you probably need to write `<input data-bind="value: $parent.toAdd" >` or `<input data-bind="value: $root.toAdd" >` (the same is true for the `data-bind="click: add"`) but without seeing your viewmodel it is hard to tell...

Comment: newesv: I think this is it..  Just checking it out now..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `template` binding you are inside of the context of the `mydata` property.

However your `toAdd` and `add` are defined on the root level so you need to use `$root` (or `$parent` depending of the nesting level) in your bindings to access them:

```
<input data-bind="value: $root.toAdd" /> 
<button data-bind="click: $root.add">Add</button>
```

You can read more the binding contexts in the [documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html).